# Pi 4 Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop Flash

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu

I want to flash the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop image(x64) onto my Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB RAM(I have my reasons). I am looking online at tutorials. It doesn't look like many people have done this. I'm mostly finding people who recommend Ubuntu mate or Ubuntu 18.04 server. Why are people recommending Server? Is it because it's lighter weight?

Comment: Probably because you can install the lightweight server, then build up the small number of packages needed to make the desktop work.

Comment: Note that *x64* is a common abbreviation for *x86-64*, not *arm64*, which I presume is what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure opinions are allowed here so I'll try to limit this:

1. LTS support Server 20.04.2 has 4 extra years
2. 20.04.2 is available in 32 and 64 bit versions
3. Desktop downloads from [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) is noted as being 'development' as it version 20.10
4. Size - server is a smaller image

For me - In daily use most of the Pi machines I connect to are headless so do not need a desktop image.